# How can I determine the common cryptographic suites I need to enable on my browser for common websites?

Tags: tls, windows, web-browser

How do I determine the common cryptographic suites I need to enable on my browsers (I use IE11, Firefox/Nightly 49, Chrome 51) running on Windows for common websites, for eg, www.google.com, www.w3.org, www.microsoft.com, etc?

The end game is to ensure that all (the above listed) browsers can access the specified sites I'm interested in.

Comment: Why not use the default settings?

Answer (score 1):

To see which cipher suites are used by the browsers have a look at the [client tests at SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html) (you need to look at the details for each browser). But it might be better to simply use known good configurations like [the recommended configurations from Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations).

Comment: Or if the servers are on public net (at 443), use SSLLabs server test and it includes a list of common browsers/clients and whether each will work with that server, so you don't have to manually compare versions, ciphers, etc.